# How should I write scraper that searched for a constant button targeted at one domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to scrape an entire domain ex(Tumblr.com) and search each blog for an embedded tag. Can this be done with rails?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple question to answer.

I would point you to:

http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

sure, if this tag has an css selector (id, class) or a specific XPATH that you can search for, you should use [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) a powerful ruby library.

Something like

```
agent.page.search(".mytag").each do |item|
  day = item.at("a").text

  item.search("p").each do |e|
   image   = e.at("a")
   agent.get(image).save_as("images/img#{rand(1000)}_#{File.basename image}")
  end
end
```